# Creating a numpy array of evenly sampled values from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Say I have a list of values, e.g.: [9, 17, 2]

What is the best way to create an n-dimensional numpy array (e.g.: [110 x 90 x 11] say) populated by the values in the list randomly, but evenly sampled?

Comment: Something wrong with `np.random.choice`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

)you can select numbers randomly with random.randrange

```
import random
import numpy as np

l=[9, 17, 2]
arrayshape=[110,90,11]

#random.randrange(len(l)) generates random indexes
#l[random.randrange(len(l))] select random indexes from list
#for i in range(110*90*11) how many number we need
#np.array(...) make an array from list
#np.reshape(... ,arrayshape) reshaping array to our shape
array=np.reshape(np.array([l[random.randrange(len(l))] for i in range(110*90*11)]),arrayshape)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
np.random.choice(arr, (9, 17, 2))
```

[`random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) will by default pick a random sample from `arr` with uniform probability and with replacement (and with the given shape).

Comment: You can use the shape directly in `choice`,  no need to flatten and reshape.